# How to replace identity-obj-proxy for jest snapshot testing with images

Tags: image, react-native, mocking, jestjs, snapshot

When I run the Jest testing suite for my React Native project (powered by Ignite Andross 2.1.0), I get the following error:

> console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
>
> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'source' supplied to 'Image'.
>         in Image (created by ConvoCard)
>         in ConvoCard
>         in View (created by Component)
>         in Component

The origin of the error is that I'm supposed to be passing a png file into the component `ConvoCard`, as the `source` prop of a react-native `Image` component, but in the testing environment, this asset was getting corrupted.

After some digging around, I was able to see that when I ran react-native normally, the required asset console-logged to a number, and when I ran the test suite, it console-logged to an empty object, because of this line in my `package.json` file, which uses `identity-obj-proxy`:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
```

AFAIK, this is the expected behavior of `identity-obj-proxy`; it is used to replace all `require(asset)` statements in the code with a special object that mocks any method it is called with; so I'm not sure how to proceed. I have no idea how my `require()` statements are getting replaced by numbers when my code is run in the development environment (is that the Metro bundler?), so I don't know how to supply these numbers to the `Image` `source` property, when running Jest, to properly mock required assets.

I would love an answer to that, as well as a quick explanation of how/why the Metro bundler (if it is the Metro bundler) is replacing my assets with numbers, as the bundler is sparsely documented. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Steve Kellock at Infinte Red, I was able to find a fix to the problem: replace `identity-obj-proxy` in `package.json` with the newer `jest-transform-stub` --- and yes, it is the Metro Bundler that does the replacement of image assets with numbers (though if anyone is still interested, I would be fascinated to hear anything about how that process works under the hood).